# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 : Can a GL_FLOAT texture be assigned to a FBO as a COLOR attachment?

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, fbo

I want to get the value using *GL_FLOAT texture* by glReadPixels.

My Android device support *OES_texture_float*. but, it became an error to attach *GL_FLOAT* texture.

In OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android, to attach *GL_FLOAT* texture to FBO is impossible? Or depend on hardware?

Part of my code is:

Init:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,texWidth,texHeight,0,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
```

FBO Attach:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,framebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture,0);
checkGlError("FBO Settings");
// glGetError() return 0x502.
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
// glCheckFramebufferStatus() return 0.
```

If anyone has some insight i'd ppreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The unextended OpenGL ES 2.0 does not allow FBOs of this type, however there are some extensions (and some mobile GPUs) that supports floating point buffers. Take a look at [GL_OES_texture_float](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) and [GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments.txt).

nVidia Tegra 3 supports floating point FBOs.

P.S. With Tegra 2 it also seems to be possible: http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/devforum/discussion/1576/tegra-2-slow-floating-point-texture-operations/p1

Comment: Could you give us any proof of this fact?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! "Take a look at GL_OES_texture_float" means that written in the text about GL_OES_texture_float of khronos?

Comment: I have extended my answer and added some links.